# Why do my weighing scales have ml and g?

Tags: measuring-scales, weights

My electric weighing scales allow me to set the weighing unit to various different units.  2 of the units are `g` (grams) and `ml` (milliliters).  However, considering 1ml at sea level should weigh 1g (and this is borne out in the scales' value; 100ml of water also weighs 100g), is there any particular reason these 2 units of measurement are separate rather than a combined "g/ml" measure?

Comment: There are lots of people that doesn't know that. It's really cleaver. Think about it, "this scale can also measure water for you! " "Oh yeah it even has a ml mode, how convenient!"......

Comment: @user3528438 sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Perhaps it also has a barometer built-in?

Comment: g/ml would be density and confusing

Comment: My scale also has this. My first thought was "ml of _what_?" and then I decided never to use that feature because it can't possibly work. But I'm curious as to what it's _trying_ to accomplish.

Comment: @Erik Most water-based liquids, including, surprisingly, milk, are close enough to the same 1g/ml density as water that for small amounts this would be accurate enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well as a chemist the densities of water and any watery liquid like milk will be very close to 1 gram per milliliter (g/ml) -- within a few percent. However corn oil would be off since it is about 0.90 g/ml. Lard seems to be about 0.87 g/ml. So be careful, but I'd guess that most ingredients in a recipe would work if within 10%.

Comment: The point is, aren't my scales just giving me the "grams" value for "ml"?  It's not like they can detect the liquid being weighed.

Comment: Correct. The balance is weighing grams and just displaying that as milliliters assuming 1.00 gram per milliliter.  The point is that the balance can't detect if you weighing water or oil. So for water the ml value will be good. For oil there will be about 10% too much.